# Create a Pandas table with nested document of MongoDB

Tags: python, pandas

I need create a table using Pandas with nested documents in MongoDB.

This is my json:

```
{
"CNPJ" : "65206503000163",
"CNAE" : [ 
        {
            "codigoCNAE" : 7911200,
            "dataInicioCNAE" : 20000101,
        },
        {
            "codigoCNAE" : 9999999,
            "dataInicioCNAE" : 2018101,
        }
        ]
}
```

I need a simple table:

```
    CNPJ             codigoCNAE     dataInicioCNAE 
0   65206503000163   7911200        20000101      
1   65206503000163   9999999        2018101
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have only one such document you can use the following code.

```
dict1 = { "CNPJ" : "65206503000163", "CNAE" : [{ "codigoCNAE" : 7911200, "dataInicioCNAE" : 20000101, }, { "codigoCNAE" : 9999999, "dataInicioCNAE" : 2018101, } ] }

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1['CNAE'])
df['CNPJ'] = dict1['CNPJ']
```

OUTPUT :

```
print(df)

   codigoCNAE dataInicioCNAE     CNPJ
0   7911200   20000101          65206503000163
1   9999999   2018101           65206503000163
```

For multiple documents you can iterate through each document and use `pd.concat` to combine each df

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

dict1 = { "CNPJ" : "65206503000163", 
          "CNAE" : [{ "codigoCNAE" : 7911200, 
                     "dataInicioCNAE" : 20000101, }, 
                      { "codigoCNAE" : 9999999, 
                        "dataInicioCNAE" : 2018101, } ] }

df = json_normalize(dict1, ['CNAE'],'CNPJ')
print (df)
   codigoCNAE  dataInicioCNAE            CNPJ
0     7911200        20000101  65206503000163
1     9999999         2018101  65206503000163
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
import pandas as pd 

x = {
"CNPJ" : "65206503000163",
"CNAE" : [ 
        {
            "codigoCNAE" : 7911200,
            "dataInicioCNAE" : 20000101,
        },
        {
            "codigoCNAE" : 9999999,
            "dataInicioCNAE" : 2018101,
        }
        ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, orient='columns')
df = pd.concat([df['CNAE'].apply(pd.Series), df['CNPJ']], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
codigoCNAE        dataInicioCNAE            CNPJ                                                                                         
0     7911200        20000101       65206503000163                                                                                         
1     9999999         2018101       65206503000163
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a `dataframe` from the `dict` you have, seperate the `dataframe` to 2 parts. Make the `CNAE` part as a `Series` and `concat` with the other part on axis 1.

```
 x = {
    "CNPJ" : "65206503000163",
    "CNAE" : [ 
                {
                    "codigoCNAE" : 7911200,
                    "dataInicioCNAE" : 20000101,
                },
                {
                    "codigoCNAE" : 9999999,
                    "dataInicioCNAE" : 2018101,
                }
            ]
}

x_df = pd.DataFrame(x)

a_df = x_df['CNAE'].apply(pd.Series)
b_df = x_df['CNPJ']

df = pd.concat([b_df, a_df], axis=1)

df

#Output

CNPJ    codigoCNAE  dataInicio    CNAE
0   65206503000163  7911200     20000101
1   65206503000163  9999999     2018101
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat`:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> pd.concat([df[['CNPJ']],pd.DataFrame(d['CNAE'])],axis=1)
             CNPJ  codigoCNAE  dataInicioCNAE
0  65206503000163     7911200        20000101
1  65206503000163     9999999         2018101
>>>
```